# Cannot install stable Xbox 360 driver

Tags: 12.04, xbox-360

When I type in >>

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:grumbel/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install xboxdrv
```

then when I go to install the stable driver like this >>

```
sudo apt-get install xboxdrv-stable
```

I get this >>

```
mohd-arafat-hossain@TUD:~$ sudo apt-get install xboxdrv-stable
[sudo] password for mohd-arafat-hossain: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package xboxdrv-stable
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because the developer (*grumbel*) has only released `xboxdrv` for Ubuntu 12.04 yet, NOT `xboxdrv-stable`. I don't know the difference, but try

`sudo apt-get install xboxdrv`

and your problem should most probably be solved.

Comment: I did mention of doing sudo apt-get install xboxdrv successfully in my question.....read again :/

Comment: Is there any other stable xbox controller drivers out? every site i visit it points me to grumble :/

Comment: @MohdArafatHossain:  That's because grumbel *is* the developer! See his page. You're not supposed to install BOTH drivers even if they are available. In your case you don't have an option since no -stable is available for precise. What are your problems with `xboxdrv` anyway??

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/142783/wrong-button-input-response-when-using-xbox-controller and on some random site I visited on the net it said to install the stable driver then I can overcome this issue.

Comment: As its not available on Precise I guess this case ends here :/